# Calculating score/Points of the Quiz game

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup

Can I calculate the score/points before the options (radio buttons) shuffle as in code below. Before `Collection.shuffle()`, the options are fixed as the `correctChoice` will always be assigned to `c2` radio button. So can I use like

```
if (c2.isSelected())
score=score+2;
```

and after that I shuffle the choices.

```
QsL.setText(Question.get(i).getQs().toString());  
c1.setText(Question.get(i).getChoiceOne());
c2.setText(Question.get(i).getCorrectChoice());
c3.setText(Question.get(i).getChoiceTwo());
scorelbl.setText(Question.get(i).getScore());
if (c2.isSelected()) { 
    score=score+2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,score);
}
String one = Question.get(i).getChoiceOne();
String two = Question.get(i).getChoiceTwo();
String three = Question.get(i).getCorrectChoice();
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);
Collections.shuffle(choices);
c1.setText(choices.get(0).toString());
c2.setText(choices.get(1).toString());
c3.setText(choices.get(2).toString());
```

Thanks for your answers in advance. I have edited this post.

Comment: If you say `Arrays.<String>asList(one, two, three)` you can remove all of the `toString()` calls.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson but it will not solve my problem. For now, it works , I mean the correctChoice(Answer) comes random among the three radio button options

Comment: I know it won't solve the problem. That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your fragment shuffles strings, which obscures the correct answer. Instead, associate each choice's *text*, *correct* state, and the *button* to which it was assigned:

```
class Choice {
    String text;
    Boolean correct;
    JRadioButton button;
}
```

Let `Question` contain a `List<Choice> choices`, ready to be shuffled and assigned to buttons. In a button's action `ActionListener`, search the `choices` for the matching button to determine the selected choice's correctness. Update the score accordingly.

Comment: please excuse me but I could not understand your suggestion. Can you provide me some details.?

Comment: Also is it possible if I calculate the score before the Shuffle of choices ?

Comment: You can't calculate the score until the question is answered; for more specific guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: I have edit the post now if you can comment plz because this problem is not going to solve.

Comment: Absent your [mcve], I don't know how to make your approach work. I'm not sure where you're having trouble implementing my approach.

Comment: @ trashgod, I really did not understand what you suggested me ? That is why I requested you to please explain it a bit. What you suggest I should have another class for choices or what?

Comment: Your fragment dos not show `Question`; it's capitalized like a class but has instance methods suggestive of a `List` instance; Absent your [mcve], I'm guessing. I'm suggesting that  `Question` be a class the contains a `List<Choice>` named `choices`.

Comment: Question is a list like:  List<QuestionsInfo> Question in my main class Quiz.java; All the data including queries are in this class. Then there is QuestionInfo.java class where I have setter/getter and variables like String Qs;String ChoiceOne; etc.

Comment: Your [mcve] will show that more clearly than a series of comments.